# using .htaccess to find subdomain files

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, subdomain

I have a site `example.com` whose files are at `/path/to/example/` It has subdomains `subdomain.example.com` whose files are at `/path/to/example/subdomain/` How can I serve these files using `.htaccess` without redirection?

I tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://example.com/subdomain/$1 [L]
```

but this redirects users to a new page.

I also tried

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdomain/$1 [L]
```

but this gives a server error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =subdomain.example.com
RewriteRule !^subdomain/ subdomain%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

Comment: This doesn't redirect [good] but serves the files at  `/path/to/example/` [bad]

Comment: Perfect. Can you explain (or point me towards an explanation of) how your solution works?

Comment: `!^subdomain/` is a negative match which means if current URI is not starting with `/subdomain/` then route all requests to `/subdomain/<uri>`